# bug on validation when p:treeTable is present

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces, omnifaces

I just found a bug with JSF Primefaces and need some help here.

In a facelet (xhtml) I have a few input text boxes that need validation (numeric range) after the user enter some value (on blur or ENTER). I use Omnifaces validator to check the min and max values in the fields.

When the validator is triggered it checks the file value. If it is valid, no problems. But if the value is not valid (out of range) the screen shows the validation error and then it hangs / freezes, blocking the user to do anything (with a light gray layer that is used to avoid user action on screen). To recover I have to hit the browser's Refresh buttton (F5 does not work either).

The browser console shows an error message related to the JSON parsing in the jquery.js file (provided by Primefaces):

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 1".

I hacked the jquery.js file to show the JSON content and, indeed, it is malformed (contains an extra comma):

> {,"validationFailed":true}

When the validation is fine, the is no extra comma in the JSON content.

> {"validationFailed":true}

Doing some tests I found out that the problem is cause bacause there is a treeTable component in the same facelet, which makes the validator incompatible. When I remove the treeTable component from the facelets, the validator works fine. Also realizes the the sortBy parameter in the treeTable is causing it. If I keep the treeTable and remove the sortBy argument it works also.

I am using java 8 (OpenJDK 1.8), Tomcat 7, JSF 2.2.10, PrimeFaces 5.2, PrimeFaces Extensions 3.2.0, OmniFaces 1.14, Spring Faces 2.4.4, Spring Secutiry 3.2.8, Spring 4.2.0.

Here is the facelet code snippet:

```
<ui:composition
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:casper="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components"
xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags">

...

    <p:inputText id="discountPercent" widgetVar="discountPercentVar" value="#{myBean.discountPercent}" required="#{editable}">
        <p:ajax listener="#{myBean.calculateDiscount()}" update="pricingFields" process="@widgetVar(dcDiscountPercentVar)" />
        <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="2" minFractionDigits="2"/>
        <o:validator validatorId="javax.faces.DoubleRange" minimum="#{myBean.minimumDiscount}" maximum="#{myBean.maximumDiscount}" message="#{of:format2(msg.error_discount, myBean.minimumDiscount, myBean.maximumDiscount)}" />
    </p:inputText>

    ...

    <!-- Pricing Tree -->
    <p:treeTable id="totals" var="node" value="#{myBean.pricingTree}" sortBy="#{node.UIName}">
        <p:column headerText="#{msg.qPricingGrid_breakdown}">
            <h:outputText value="#{node.UIName}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="#{msg.qPricingGrid_quantity}" style="text-align:right">
            <casper:quantity-field class="delivery-units-column" value="#{node.deliveryUnits}"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:treeTable>
```

Any Thoughts?

Comment: Does it work without your composite component? If not, remove it. Does it work if not used in a template? Then remove the template. Create a [mcve]. And tried a newer PF version?

Comment: And your 2 jason strings both say validation failed!

Comment: The second json is fine and valid. 
A newer PrimeFaces version causes one of the components to break the layout, so upgrading is not an option now (before we figure out what is wrong).